# how to avoid the pre-clicked state on ngdialog

Tags: ng-dialog

I'm using ngDialog to display the content on the page, but for some reason it shows the dialog's head in pre clicked view.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: maybe you need to set trapfocus:false

Comment: @jckim0414  Didnt work.

Comment: You could always fix the header styling with CSS: `.header:focus { outline:none; }`. Would that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old question, but as far as it's not answered still, I leave this answer in order to help people who is leaded here.

```
ngDialog.open({ template: 'template.html', trapFocus: false});
```

"trapFocus: false" will do the trick, I hope it helps. Cheers!